# Visually indicating the active control (for controls that don’t show focus rect)

Tags: windows, mfc, focus, indicator

I’m writing a little Windows application which has two list-view-controls. I have set it up so that the user can tab (focus) between the two, but I need a way of visually indicating which is the active control. I don’t want to go to the trouble of messing with owner-drawn controls, so I experimented with some of the different window styles like *border* and *client edge*, but none look good. I decided to toggle the *disabled* property because it looks best and is easy to use.

The problem now is that I have the controls set up so that whenever the user clicks on either one, it grabs the focus (calls `SetFocus()`, sets a handle to itself, etc.) but of course, disabled controls don’t get event notifications like mouse clicks.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can retain the visual distinction of the active control and also be able to toggle the active window with the mouse?

Comment: A list box already knows how to indicate the focus.  It has a focus rectangle and makes selected items white-on-blue.  Don't help.  If you *really* need this then implement a message handler for WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX in the parent to, say, give it a distinct background color.

Comment: It’s not a list box, it’s a list control/view, and I’m not trying to indicate selected items in a list control, I’m trying to indicate which of the two list controls currently has the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans’ suggestion of using CTRLCOLOR reminded me of using that a long time ago to easily make some changes to the colors of controls which then reminded me of [`CustomDraw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761817%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I decided to use CustomDraw to indicate the currently active control because it is even easier, and yet provides even better control.